# How to make an SQL select query between two field with LIKE operator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I want to select records by comparing two similar text field in ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 (data stored in an ORACLE ArcSDE database).

I'm looking to select all records where field1 contain a string that is a part of the string in field2 (both fiels on the same table).

(field1 is the name and field2 the location, usually I have a name like "School" and a location like "Example street" but sometime the name is "House on this street" and the location is "this street", my goal is to filter these)

I know how to compare a field with part of a string :

```
field1 LIKE '%string%'
```

But I can't get it to work with two field, I tried lots of variation of

```
field1 LIKE '%field2%'
```

or

```
field1 LIKE '%' & field2 & '%'
```

But it never work, I get error messages like invalid character or missing closing parenthesis.

So is it possible to compare two field with the LIKE operator and how ?

Comment: you need a JOIN

Comment: This is a pure SQL question, without a GIS focus. Once you have the SQL right, you can edit this question if you have trouble using it from ArcMap. You should certainly specify which exact RDBMS is in use, since each has different string manipulation tools available (with very different syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double pipe symbol is Concatenation and works when I query a file geodatabase.
field1 like '%' || field2 || '%'

Comment: That work perfectly, I just have to add an UPPER to made the selection case insensitive